# Java.lang.String cannot be converted to Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

In my code I am trying to automate a payment, but I can't get my clickHold to work on line 79-80. I have selenium, and java_client in my profile for the project.

Error 80 java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.Webelements.

Error on this line.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(redButton).build().perform();
```

Am I missing something in my code, or in my lines?

Here is my code.

```
 @Test
public void CheckIn() throws InterruptedException {

    //Wait for the 'Get Started' icon to be available to click
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(profile)));

    //Tap the 'Profile' icon
    driver.findElement(By.id(profile)).click();

    //Tap the 'Hamburger' icon on the bottom left corner
    driver.findElement(By.id(sign)).click();

    //Enter Username
    driver.findElement(By.id(enterUsernameButton)).sendKeys("qa713confirmed@mailinator.com");

    //Enter Password
    driver.findElement(By.id(enterPasswordButton)).sendKeys("2017");

    //Tap the DONE button
    driver.findElement(By.id(signUpDoneButton)).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(profile)));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(redButton).build().perform();

    //Tap the red button
    driver.findElement(By.id(redButton)).click();

    //Tap the "Sounds Good!"
    driver.findElement(By.id(good)).click();

    //Wait for Red Button
    driver.findElement(By.id(locator)).click();

    //Check in stall
    driver.findElement(By.id(stall)).click();

    //Type in "23"
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(stallnumber)).sendKeys("23");
}
```

Comment: What is that title? Is it exception? Is it compilation problem? Where does it happen, on what line? What is `redButton` (since you don't mention it in code snippets anywhere)? Why did I have to ask so many questions when it is you who wanted some help?

Comment: Please include error stack trace and as more code samples as possible, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Got it still very new to the site, but I updated my post and hopefully this helps.

Comment: No worries @VellJackson, we all struggled with asking questions when first joining the site. Welcome to stack :) Thank you for formatting the code

Comment: @mrfreester Thank you very much

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("redButton")).click(); You should use id like this way

Comment: yes I used that under the line 82, but I want to press and hold "redButton" before I click it. @zsbappa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your naming conventions and how you used it later as I don't see where it's declared, I assume `redButton` is a string representing an `ID` or other selector.

In this line:

```
action.clickAndHold(redButton).build().perform();
```

`clickAndHold` is expecting a `WebElement`, but you're giving it a string object, hence the error:

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.Webelement

So you would need to do something like this.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement redButtonElement = driver.findElement(By.id(redButton));
action.clickAndHold(redButtonElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: In the line 

action.clickAndHold(redButtonElement).build().perform();

"action" is a error. How do I move past this error?

Comment: I'm assuming you still had this line in your code from your example: `Actions action = new Actions(driver);` That should be before you use the `action` variable. I'll update the answer with that entire snippet. For what it's worth, if you have further problems, it would help if you mentioned what the error was. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much! @mrfreester

Comment: No problem @VellJackson, if you feel like this answered your question or was useful, feel free to upvote and/or click the check to mark it as the accepted answer. Best of luck.